# How to get value JSON array without passing index number in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I do this by using `Idents[0].IsVerified` but I do not want to give index number. I need to check which block is associate with `PrimaryEmail` or `Mobile`. This is my JSON:

```
"Idents": [
  {
    "PrimaryEmail": "abc@gmail.com",
    "IsVerified": false,
    "IdentId": 1,
    "EmailVerificationCode": 302284
  },
  {
    "Mobile": "1234567890",
    "IsVerified": true,
    "IdentId": 2,
    "MobileVerificationCode": 302284
  },
  {
    "CardNumber": 0,
    "IsVerified": false,
    "IdentId": 4
  }
]
```

Comment: What _exactly_ do you expect to get? Give an example.

Comment: I have PrimaryEmail and I want to check which block contain it.

Comment: Use a loop or a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Python does support JSON directly. First, you must convert JSON into lists and dictionaries (module `json` has the necessary tools). Assuming you've done the conversion and the JSON array is in the list `Idents`, look through the list and check which list items have the key `"Mobile"`:

```
[block for block in Idents if "Mobile" in block]
#[{'MobileVerificationCode': 302284, 'IdentId': 2, 'IsVerified': True, 
#  'Mobile': '1234567890'}]
```

The same result can be obtained by filtering:

```
list(filter(lambda block: "Mobile" in block, Idents))
#[{'MobileVerificationCode': 302284, 'IdentId': 2, 'IsVerified': True, 
#  'Mobile': '1234567890'}]
```